# Text entered with Watir keeps disappearing

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

We are using react and have the following code for a Province text field in our address form:

```
<input name="province" class="form-control" id="province" value="" type="text">
```

When you manually select the fields there is a blue outline that appears showing that the field has focus. After typing in AB or Alberta and then giving focus to another field, the Province text is altered to ALBERTA. When using Watir-Webdriver I was able to use the .set method to enter the text in this field and it would work the same as if I manually entered the text. I recently had to upgrade to Watir 6.2.0 and can no longer require Watir-Webdriver, only Watir. Now when I run my code and set the Province field to AB or Alberta, when I give focus to another field the text entered into the Province field is blanked out. If I manually click the field while the test is running, then the replacement works. It appears that Watir is no longer giving this field focus the way Watir-Webdriver did. I've tried the following to give it focus:

```
BROWSER.text_field(:id => 'city').send_keys :tab #tab from previous field
BROWSER.text_field(:id => 'province').fire_event :onmousedown
BROWSER.text_field(:id => 'province').fire_event :onmouseup
BROWSER.text_field(:id => 'province').fire_event :onblur
BROWSER.text_field(:id => 'province').fire_event :onfocus
BROWSER.text_field(:id => 'province').click
```

I tried both .set and .send_keys to enter the text. The developer hasn't changed anything to this form from when I had it working with Watir-Webdriver. Any ideas what changed with Watir that I can no longer get this Province field to behave like it did with Watir-Webdriver? I'm still using the Firefox browser like I was with Watir-Webdriver:

```
BROWSER = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
```

Answer (score 2):

We had a conversation about this issue in the Watir Channel on [Selenium Slack](http://seleniumhq.herokuapp.com/). The conclusion was that React was not recognizing the Selenium commands as actually making a change, so the value from the virtual DOM was being re-rendered.

This might not be the best (or long term) solution, but he solved it by using `Browser#execute_script` on the element with this:

```
var triggerChange = function(element) {
  var event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
  element.dispatchEvent(event);
}
triggerChange(arguments[0])
```

We might need to figure out how to build something into Watir that does this automatically.

Comment: I am little confused, Is it not true that watir-webdriver also used selenium webdriver? What difference then?

Comment: Well, `watir-webdriver ` is deprecated in favor of just `watir `. But yes, Watir sends Selenium commands to a browser driver or a Selenium server as applicable.

Comment: Yes, but he says that watir-webdriver does that Job which recent watir fails to do, So I am asking watir-webdriver also used selenium right? So, why this problem hasn't happened while he was using watir-webdriver?

Comment: Ah yes, it used selenium as well, but Watir 6.0 added a number of features and optimizations which could change how things are loaded.

Comment: No matter whatever is added, at the bottom, it still execute the selenium code, for an example, if you execute `b.text_field(:id,'something').set 'raj'` then it goes through number of checking which is done by watir and then it execute the selenium code `driver.find_element(:id,'something').send_keys 'raj'`, So why problem?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has more to do with what React is doing with the virtual DOM than what Watir/Selenium is doing.

Comment: I seem to be getting the following error:
    syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' (SyntaxError)
        var event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });

Comment: @titusfortner Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be prettiest workaround, but we were able to use following java script to fix this.

```
browser.execute_script("$('textarea#NameOfTextArea').val('#{text_to_enter}')")
```

I used textarea, In your case you might want to change it to 'text_field'.